# New Filter of Gmail for auto movetrash specific subjects with time condition. Warning: it never matches the incoming email

Tags: gmail

I want to make **filters in Gmail** email with **certain subjects automatically deleted if more than 1 day from *example@gmail.com***. but when the filter is entered there is a warning from gmail:

`Filter searches containing "label:", "in:", "is:", date range (e.g. "before:" or "after:") or stars criteria (e.g. "has:yellow-star") are not recommended as they will never match incoming emails. Do you still wish to continue to the next step?`

How do you do it in the latest version (Gmail)?
I want to delete emails with certain subjects more than 1 day from example@gmail.com, how do that?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Google Script: 
- Open: https://script.google.com 
- Click File => New => Script File 
- Type this code

```
// reference: https://medium.com/@fw3d/a-cleaning-robot-for-your-gmail-inbox-f44c01306ea2

// Modify by: Dicky Ibrohim for delete (move to trash) specific subject, sender, and time

function removetotrash() {

  var delayDays = 1; // Impact form email more than 1day
  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays); 

  // What will be executed, adjust the string here
  var searches = [
    '"SUBJECT WANT SEARCH TO DELETE" from:example@gmail.com'
    ];

  // Looping for 500 last email
  var threads = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < searches.length; i++) {
    var tmp_threads = GmailApp.search(searches[i], 0, 500); // search until 500 mail
    var threads = threads.concat(tmp_threads);
  }
  // Then remove all to trash
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
    {
      threads[i].moveToTrash(); 
    }
  }
}
```

- Click File => Save
- Make it work automatic: Click icon "Current project's triggers",
- Click "Create new triger"
- Setup AND SELECT intermediate time
- Save